# How to send a file to the user while in an ajax panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have a radgrid, and each row has a button sending a file to the user. The grid is in an update panel and it is vital it stays this way. Is there a way I can override the ajax panel? I cannot place the button outside the panel because it is inside the grid therefore preventing me from any action. How can I invoke this?

My AjaxPanel:

```
            <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server">
            <p style="font-family: Arial;">טבלת סוכנים</p>
            <telerik:RadGrid  runat="server" ID="gvClients" ClientSettings-EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" Skin="Glow" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvClients_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="gvClients_DataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <ClientSettings>
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                </ClientSettings>
                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HierarchyLoadMode="Client">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="seniorId" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter seniorId column" HeaderText="seniorId" SortExpression="seniorId" UniqueName="seniorId" Visible="False">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter id column" HeaderText="תעדות זהות" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" UniqueName="id">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="password" FilterControlAltText="Filter password column" HeaderText="סיסמא" SortExpression="password" UniqueName="password">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fName" FilterControlAltText="Filter fName column" HeaderText="שם פרטי" SortExpression="fName" UniqueName="fName">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="lName" FilterControlAltText="Filter lName column" HeaderText="שם משפחה" SortExpression="lName" UniqueName="lName">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="mPhone" FilterControlAltText="Filter mPhone column" HeaderText="מספר טלפון" SortExpression="mPhone" UniqueName="mPhone">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="address" FilterControlAltText="Filter address column" HeaderText="כתובת" SortExpression="address" UniqueName="address">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="sc" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter sc column" HeaderText="sc" SortExpression="sc" UniqueName="sc" Visible="False">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="email" FilterControlAltText="Filter email column" HeaderText="אימייל" SortExpression="email" UniqueName="email">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateJoined" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy}" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter dateJoined column" HeaderText="תאריך הצטרפות" SortExpression="dateJoined" UniqueName="dateJoined">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="contract" FilterControlAltText="Filter contract column" HeaderText="קובץ חוזה" SortExpression="contract" UniqueName="contract" Visible="False">
                            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
                            </ColumnValidationSettings>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="הורד קובץ" UniqueName="downloadcolumn">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadButton runat="server" CommandArgument="<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" OnCommand="btnDownload_Command1" id="btnDownload" Text="הורד"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" />
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table style="float: right; display: inline-block;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>תעודת זהות</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" MaxLength="9" ID="txtId" Width="200px" Skin="Glow" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>סיסמא</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtPassword" MaxLength="25" runat="server" Width="200px" Skin="Glow" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>שם פרטי</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtfName" MaxLength="25" runat="server" Width="200px" Skin="Glow" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>שם משפחה</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtlName" MaxLength="25" runat="server" Width="200px" Skin="Glow" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>מספר טלפון</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtmPhone" MaxLength="25" runat="server" Width="200px" Skin="Glow" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>כתובת</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAddress" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Width="200px" Skin="Glow" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>אימייל</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEmail" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Width="200px" Skin="Glow" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Skin="Glow" Width="126px" Text="עדכן" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Enabled="False" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Width="83px" Skin="Glow" Text="מחק" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" Enabled="False" />
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Width="84px" Skin="Glow" Text="הוסף" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <p>צרף חוזה</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="AsyncUpload" MultipleFileSelection="Disabled" MaxFileInputsCount="1" runat="server" Skin="Metro" Enabled="false">
                            <Localization Select="בחר קובץ" />
                        </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDone" Text="הפעולה בוצעה בהצלחה" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Enabled="false" runat="server" Skin="Glow" Text="העלה קובץ" Width="175px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Code begin on button click:

```
    protected void btnDownload_Command1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = gvClients.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
    GetUserData usr = new GetUserData(item["id"].Text, Security.level.Agent, servermap);
    string file = usr.RetrieveContractPath();
    SendFileDownload(file);
}
```

The file download function has been checked and works flawlessly. I have 100% assurance that the problem lies within the updatePanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same problem of yours,Rad Ajax Panel  doesn't support file upload and manipulation as this requires a full post-back and the panel only supports Ajax partial calls. We went around this by implementing the file handler in a Modal Dialog that runs outside of the Ajax Panel!

Hope this would help.

it Should be something like this :

```
 protected void btnDownload_Command1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = gvClients.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
    GetUserData usr = new GetUserData(item["id"].Text, Security.level.Agent, servermap);
    string file = usr.RetrieveContractPath();
   // SendFileDownload(file); dont call it here , call it in the other window

string url = "PopupFileDownload.aspx?file="+file;
    string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);

}
```

//then in the popupFileDownload.aspx , handle the Page_load like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 SendFileDownload(Request.QueryString["file"]);

}
```

Comment: That sounds too complicated for me to currently comprehend. I guess i could say goodbye to by ajax on this webform.

Comment: see the edit, its not too complicated, but I guess it depends if you really need Ajax or no.

Comment: For some reason, the popup won't work. Could it be my browser is preventing it? I see no message of popup blocked and in addition when debugged those lines of code are called accordingly with not error. EDIT: it cannot be my browser I have tried 4 different browser and yield the same result. But is is important to note I am using Telerik's Ajax panel, not ASP. Because telerik supports having tables in the panel.

Comment: I have concluded that the issue is still because of the Ajax panel. The telerik Ajax Panel is preventing the popup.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to add an invisible server button outside the grid and invoke it's postback via javascript. Here is the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdDownload" runat="server" Visible="False" />
```

Then, add some javascript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goFile(id) { __doPostBack('<%=cmdDownload.UniqueID %>', id);}
</script>
```

Next, modify your button in your grid as follows:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <button type="button" onclick="goFile('<%#Container.ItemIndex%>')">הורד</button>
</ItemTemplate>
```

When your download button click event fires, you can get the Index of the item via `Request.Params("__EventArgument")` and send the file to the user.

You might need to tweak the code a bit to make it work but I've used this successfully in many cases.

Comment: Though your solution is smarter and simpler it requires me to use the html button which isn't nearly as good looking as telerik's controls. But this will come in handy in the near future. Thanks!

Comment: You can use any other HTML in the ItemTemplate. All you need to do is the handle the onclick event to fire the javascript. If you wish, you can see the rendered HTML of the Telerik button and use that.